# Localization stings when differ order of numbers

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I'm doing language localization of a Swift iOS app to Chinese.
How can I translate a "%d of %d last weeks" which for English is "1 out of the 2 last weeks" but becomes "最近2周有1周" in Chinese.

How can I do a localization where **"..A..B.."** should become **"..B..A.."** in another language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use positional index of parameters, so instead of using %@ as the placeholder, use %1$@ instead. Positional placeholders allow translators to change the order of placeholders or repeat them if necessary.

For example use "%1$d of %2$d last weeks" as a key so in Chinese you can have in the translation: `"%1$d of %2$d last weeks" = "最近%2$d周有%1$d周"`. And in code:

```
let template = NSLocalizedString("%1$d of %2$d last weeks", comment: "")
let str = String.localizeStringWithFormat(template, 1, 2)
```