# Swift Localization: String String interpolation

Tags: swift, xcode, localization

I am trying to add multilanguage support to my app. I am doing this by replacing all my User visible Strings with localized strings. For strings like "Cancel", this is easy. But I have just as many strings that are interpolated with information. And the hard part is that each language would build the sentence differently.

For example: How would I localize the following String:
"Please enter the 4-digit Code sent to you at (user.PhoneNumber)"

In German, I want the string to look like this:
"Bitte gebe den 4-Ziffer Code ein, den wir dir an (user.PhoneNumber) gesendet haben"

Or in French:
"Entrez le code à 4 chiffres qui vous a été envoyé à (user.PhoneNumber)"

I am trying to find a way to use some kind of variable inside of my localization file like this (I know that this does not work):

Inside my ViewController:

```
title.text = "Please enter the 4-digit Code sent to you at %phoneNumber%".localized
```

Inside my Localizable.string

```
"Please enter the 4-digit Code sent to you at %phoneNumber%" = "Bitte gebe den 4-Ziffer Code ein, den wir dir an %phoneNumber% gesendet haben"
```

What's the best practice to do this? This must be some common issue people are having. Languages are so different!

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71621382/2894790 answer your question? It has the best practice advice and an example

Comment: @ChristosKoninis it probably would if I would understand the syntax. I don't get when to use % ect and how to use the template...

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1

Comment: Have you tested that .localized modifier? Do you know for sure that it works the same as wrapping a string in NSLocalizedString()?

Answer (score 0):

my localized file example:

"email_error_message" = "a link is sent to %@ please verify"

Actual code implementation:

let email = smth@email.com

let message = NSLocalizedString("email_error_message", comment: "error, wrong email")

let str = String.localizedStringWithFormat(message, email) //we want to replace %@ with email.

Print(str)

** Please note the replaced string/char, in the above case (email) won't be localized.